# 'testrunner.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: soapui

> 'testrunner.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I'm seeing this error while I run my tests using "Launch TestRunner" option in sopaui pro

Comment: How did you install SoapUI? How are you running it? What exactly does the command window (at the bottom of this page http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html ) say?

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown from `cmd.exe` due `testrunner.bat` is not found.

Normally when you execute `Launch TestRunner` option from SOAPUI, it executes the follow command in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin`:

`cmd.exe /C testrunner.bat <arguments>`

Since `testrunner.bat` is located in this directory this command must works, however maybe there is some error in your environment. Check if `testrunner.bat` exists an is located in `SOAPUI_HOME\bin` directory.

Alternatively you can try adding `SOAPUI_HOME\bin` directory in your environment `PATH` in order to execute `testrunner.bat` for every location, doing this probably you'll solve your problem.

Hope this helps,